# Probability of a subset with specific probabilities for each element

Tags: combinatorics

There is a set of m elements and I have a subset of n (0<n<m) elements built according to the following procedure:

1. Pick up a random element
2. Look up the probability to keep this specific element on a table specifying its fixed probability
3. Get a random number to decide, according to the probability of 2, if the element will be kept or discarded.
4. Repeat the process until either

   a.    n elements are kept, or

   b.    the number of elements kept + the
   number of elements remaining = n. In this case all remaining elements
   are kept regardless of its probability

**I need a generic algorithm to calculate the probability of any specific subset.**

A simple example with elements E1 E2 and E3 (m=3) and probabilities

p1=0.5
p2=0.4
p3=0.2

Which is the probability to get the subset E1 (n=1) ?

Favourable cases (element Ei, probability to get it, probability to keep (if E1= or to NOT keep )if not E1 ...

```
E1  1/3 0.5             
E2  1/3 1-0.4   E1  1/2 0.5 
                E3  1/2 1-0.2   E1
E3  1/3 1-0.2   E1  1/2 0.5 
                E2  1/2 1-0.4   E1
```

So, the probability to get the subset E1 is

p(E1) = 1/3 * 0.5 + 1/3 * 0.6 * (1/2 * 0.5 + 1/2 * 0.8) + 1/3 * 0.8 * (1/2 * 0.5 + 1/2 * 0.6) = 0.4433

and

p(E2) = 1/3 * 0.4 + 1/3 * 0.5 * (1/2 * 0.4 + 1/2 * 0.8) + 1/3 * 0.8 * (1/2 * 0.4 + 1/2 * 0.5) = 0.3533

p(E3) = 1/3 * 0.2 + 1/3 * 0.5 * (1/2 * 0.2 + 1/2 * 0.6) + 1/3 * 0.6 *(1/2 * 0.2 + 1/2 * 0.5) = 0.2033

I have been able to generalize this method and get a generic algorithm when n=1, but unable to obtain a generic one for any n.

============================================

Probability to get the subset Ek with m elements and probabilities pi

$$ p(Ek) = \sum_{j=1}^m pk'' Combi^{j-1} \frac{1}{j * C(^m_j)}$$

Where
pk'' = 1 when j=m

pk'' = pk when j<>m

and $Combi^j$ means all different products of j elements *(1-pi)* with i<>k

*Unsure is the explanation is clear, let’s see an example:*

For m=4, k=2

```
j=1 ...   p2 / 4 +                              (*no elements*)

j=2 ...   p2 [(1-p1) + (1-p3) + (1-p4)] / 12 +              (*all single elements*)

j=3 ...   p2 [(1-p1) (1-p3) + (1-p1) (1-p4) + (1-p3) (1-p4)] / 12 +     (*all possible duplets*)

j=4 ...   (1-p1) (1-p3) (1-p4) / 4                      (*all possible triplets*)
```

Comment: Probabilities cannot take the value $2$. And what was the point of looking up the keep-probability in a table if you immediately ignore that and assign the probability to be 2?

Comment: Sorry, probably my english was not good enough. I have not assigned a probability of 2 to any event. Where do you see that?

Comment: "according to the probability of 2" means according to the probability specified in point 2. of the explanation of the procedure. It doesn't mean that the probability is 2. I thought the example was clear enough ... :( @Michael